# How do Moq and NHibernate automatically create derived types?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, moq

When using NHibernate, you define your entites with virtual methods, and NHibernate will create a proxy object that tracks changes to your object.

In Moq, the framework will magically create a derived type from an interface or a base class. e.g.

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
IFoo magicFoo = mock.Object;
```

This is really cool.  How do these frameworks do it?  Do they use reflection, generics, some kind of dynamic compilation, or something else?

*I realize these are both open source projects, and I could go spelunking through the code, but I'd like to have a concise answer here - possibly with alternatives.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moq uses Castle Dynamic Proxy, however, just thought it would be worth adding there are also a number of other frameworks that allow you to create Proxy objects. As of NHibernate 2.1 it also allows you to use any one of the following:

- [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy)
- [LinFu Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LinFuPart1.aspx)
- [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxyfactoryobject)

Each of these projects has a brief explaination of how they achieve this, which is hopefully the kind of answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

They use a combination of reflection (to figure out what needs to be generated) and reflection-emit (to generate the derived class dynamically, and emitting IL for the methods). .NET provides both of these APIs (reflection and reflection-emit).

Comment: If you don't mind using beta stuff, the .NET Framework 4 actually lets you invoke the compiler at runtime so you can generate it from C# code instead of having to resort to ilasm, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Castle's DynamicProxy2 class.