# Is there a tool that will implement an interface by wrapping a member field or property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I find myself doing the following often enough that I feel like there must be an automated solution:

I have a wrapper class, say ListWrapper, which wraps an IList:

```
public class ListWrapper : IList 
{
    private IList _list;

    // ... Implement IList by redirecting every call to _list
}
```

Is there any tool out there that will automatically generate this implementation?

Comment: Do you mean: generate those 7 words for you?

Comment: I imagine it could be done quickly with a T4 template.  Frameworks like CSLA also have functionality like this, though they may be overkill for your needs.

Comment: @David I think T4 is the best way to go

Comment: Also, for this particular code I'd do something like `public class Wrapper { /*some code*/ }` and then `public class ListWrapper : List<Wrapper> { }` unless I need a custom implementation

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: Not sure I understand.  The major use case is taking a class and wrapping it with a little bit of custom logic.  In my example, I'm wrapping an IList, not having a list of wrappers.

Comment: Yeah..I missunderstood. In this case I'd do what @David suggested

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using ReSharper, inside the class hit "alt-insert" and then select "delegating members".

Comment: @afeygin what is related with programming in that answer? using menus of a tool?

Comment: @L.B: Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …

a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
**software tools commonly used by programmers**
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to specify explicit interface implementations at the same time to avoid multiple interface collisions?

Comment: @DavidCuccia not that I'm aware of.  You can have ReSharper explicitly implement missing members or delegating members but it doesn't look like it's smart enough to do both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Any mocking framework, and most of those use Castle Dynamic Proxy IIRC.

Take a look at Moq

Actually, here's a similar question's answer:

[auto create derived types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275433/how-do-moq-and-nhibernate-automatically-create-derived-types)

Comment: I don't want to mock or have dynamic proxies or even introduce any libraries.  This is a very simple code gen problem.